# How to filter the object values when an input is given?

Tags: html, angularjs

**HTML**

```
<input type="search" placeholder="Filter" ng-model="searchstr" ng-change="details()">       
                <table style="width:831px;overflow:auto">
                    <tr ng-repeat="d in details" ng-if="$index%3==0">
                        <td style="height:232px;width:164px;" ng-if="details[$index]">{{details[$index].CourseName}}<br>{{details[$index].Professor}}<br>{{details[$index].CourseDuration}}</td>
                        <td style="height:232px;width:164px;" ng-if="details[$index+1]">{{details[$index+1].CourseName}}<br>{{details[$index+1].Professor}}<br>{{details[$index+1].CourseDuration}}</td>
                        <td style="height:232px;width:164px;" ng-if="details[$index+2]">{{details[$index+2].CourseName}}<br>{{details[$index+2].Professor}}<br>{{details[$index+2].CourseDuration}}</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
```

**js file**

```
$scope.data=function()
            {

                $scope.details=$filter("filter")($scope.details,$scope.searchstr);

            }
```

I have tried like above but only for the first time its displaying

Comment: Is there any fiddle or plunker link

Comment: no.But i can say you that when i give any input in the input box ,the object values are displayed as the key matches from the input box.But the problem is the values are displayed only once as the $scope.details is rewrite by the matched values.So now how can i do without overwrite

Comment: How to do the same operation by creating custom filters

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `$scope.data` function. You use the builtin [angular filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter#example) like

```
<tr ng-repeat="d in details | filter:searchstr" ng-if="$index%3==0">
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it.I just changed the slight logic in js file.I am posting it as it may be helpful to somebody else.
First i just copied the $scope.details to d and filtered with the temp variable d.

```
$scope.searchstr="";
    var d=$scope.details;
    $scope.data=function()
            {

                $scope.details=$filter("filter")(d,$scope.searchstr);
            }
```